# Access website hosted in local servers without IP address from any browser inside the same company network

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-6

I've hosted `asp.net` project in our company's local server and now i want to access the portal using its virtual directory name. for eg. if the actual link to portal is `http://ipaddress/` portalname, can i access the portal by typing portalname in the address bar of any explorer?

By this users dont have to remember the exact ip where the portal is hosted intranet (as there are many servers having portals) and by just knowing the portalname they can access it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the machine name instead of the ip address.

Comment: i can not change the machine name as there are other portals hosted in the same server which has no relation to this one.

Comment: How will you be able to look for address without even knowing the address?

Comment: i have the ip address and machine name, but how could i enable users to access the portal using the name created in the iis is my concern.

Comment: machine-name/portalname/